# Having trouble deploying an app to heroku through git

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am trying to create a simple node.js app on heroku. Here is my app.js:

```js
console.log("Starting App")

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`))

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html')
})

app.get('/style', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/main.css')
})

app.get('/script', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/script.js')
})

app.get('/changelog', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/changelog.txt')
})
```

here is my package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "/App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }
}
```

and here is my Procfile:

```
web: node app.js
```

I am deploying this to heroku via github, and whenever I run the program it gives me an error, saying Cannot find module '/app/app.js.' I have made everything lowercase and removed forward slashes. I still get this error: Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js' Can anyone help?

Comment: maybe without shlash?  just app.js

Answer (score 0):

1. In package.json, change `"main": "/App.js"` to `"main": "app.js"`
2. make sure `package.json` is at the same level as `app.js`
3. If `app.js` is in another folder, make sure to provide the full path from directory holding the `package.json` file.

Comment: @Someone, is your file called `App.js` or `app.js`? Is it in the root of the repository?

Comment: @Chris it is called app.js it is in the root

Comment: How does your folder structure look like?